# How to typeset an excerpt in Lilypond (longer phrase slur and text)?

Tags: lilypond, engraving

I want to typeset following "excerpt" from a longer melody:

[image]

I currently have

```
{
\time C
(c''8 d'' e'' d'' c'' b' a' c''_"  etc.")
}
```

How could I modify it to obtain the following?

1. I would like the phrasing slur to extend to the barline, so it suggests there is more on the next bar (that is not shown).
2. The "etc." should be centered below the barline.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Slurs & phrasing slurs

The opening parenthesis for a slur is supposed to be typed *after* the first note, i.e. `c''8(`, not `(c''8`.

But, I imagine that’s supposed to be a *phrasing slur*, so perhaps you should use `\(` & `\)` rather than `(` & `)`, which are for regular slurs.

---

#### The `\shape` command

To manually position a slur (or phrasing slur, or tie) you can use the `\shape` command.  This takes four pairs of numbers `(dx . dy)` that adjust the positions of the control points of the Bézier curve.  In your case, you won’t need to adjust the first two points, but the last two will need to be moved to the right and up a bit; something like: `\shape #'((0 . 0) (0 . 0) (1 . 1) (2 . 1)) PhrasingSlur` seems to be about right.

While selecting the values for these control point adjustments, to see exactly where they are and how they are affecting the curve, you can temporarily use `\vshape` instead.

See https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/modifying-shapes#modifying-ties-and-slurs

#### The `\textEndMark` command

There are some relatively new commands `\textMark` & `\textEndMark`.  The latter comes close to what you want as it aligns with the barline, and it can be centred above on a barline with a simple `\tweak`.  Unfortunately, I’m not sure how to make these appear *below* the staff.

See
https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/writing-text#text-marks

---

#### All together

```
\version "2.24.1"

{
    \shape #'((0 . 0) (0 . 0) (1 . 1) (2 . 1)) PhrasingSlur
    c''8\( d'' e'' d'' c'' b' a' c''\)
    
    \tweak self-alignment-X #CENTER
    \textEndMark "etc." 
}
```

[image: Phrasing slur continuing until the barline, with "etc." centred above the barline]

Answer (score 5):

Adding to @Elements In Space's excellent answer, you can add a tweak to get the TextMark under the barline:

```
\version "2.24.1"

{
    \shape #'((0 . 0) (0 . 0) (1 . 1) (2 . 1)) PhrasingSlur
    c''8\( d'' e'' d'' c'' b' a' c''\)
    
    \tweak self-alignment-X #CENTER
    \tweak Y-offset -5
    \textEndMark "etc."
    
}
```